# Fetching data from an API with interpolation to search weather in a certain city

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, interpolation, fetch-api

I am trying to get weather data from an API, when fetch the data without using interpolation fetch(`https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=London&days=3`) it works fine. But when I use the code below and press enter after searching a new city I get the error message "Bad request" Parameter q is missing. Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if I can help clarify in any way.

```
import React from "react"
// import WeatherDisplay from "./WeatherDisplay";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { scryRenderedComponentsWithType } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Item from "./Item"

function SearchBar() {
    const [ defaultWeather, setDefaultWeather ] = useState([])
    const [ searchedCity, setSearchedCity ] = useState('London') 
    const [ isLoaded, setIsLoaded ] = useState(false)
    const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false); 
    const [ input, setInput ] = useState('')

    
    const searchWeather = () => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com',
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'de51889a1fmshe095099b1a97993p13134fjsnc818ad7373cb'
            }
        };
        
        fetch(`https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=${searchedCity}&days=3`, options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                setDefaultWeather(data)
                setIsLoaded(true)
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));

    }

        useEffect(() => {
            searchWeather()
            
        }, [searchedCity])
        
        
        function handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            setSearchedCity(input)
        }    

        if (!isLoaded) return  <h3>Loading...</h3>;
        
        return (
            <div>
            <form 
            className="search-form"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                <label>Search</label>
                    <input 
                    text="text" 
                    id="search"
                    
                    onChange={e => setSearchedCity(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    {/* <button>Submit</button> */}
                <div className="display">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    )    
}


export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: What is the value of the searchedCity variable? Where are you setting the value? If you are not setting it before you call searchWeather(), then it would return undefined or null.

Comment: @Jonny  - woops I added the rest of the code. So when I search a new city it works, but when I press enter after entering a new city I get that error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
instead of
onChange={e => setSearchedCity(e.target.value)}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are setting setSearchedCity in both submit and on change but In your useEffect,At least you could add conditional as:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (searchedCity) searchWeather()        
        }, [SearchedCity])
```